# RequestMapping with hibernate OneToMany how to insert the foreign key the correct way

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

So i have some trouble with the understanding of hibernate.

So i create a simple spring application with spring security. When the user logins i use a Principal to check if the user exist in the database before logging in. So i cannot do something like `User globaluser = user;`

```
@RequestMapping("/user")
public Principal user(@AuthenticationPrincipal Principal user) {

    System.out.println(user.getName());
    System.out.println(user.toString());

    return user;
}
```

I have a User class where i create a one to many relationship. But when insert into the database the fk_id_user is empty

```
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_user")
    private Integer id;


    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_id_user", nullable = false)
    private List<Client> clientList = new ArrayList<>();


    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;
// + getters and setters
```

Then i have the client controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ClientController {

    @Autowired
    private ClientDao clientDao;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);


    @RequestMapping(value = "/addclient",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void addClient(@RequestBody Client client) {

        LOGGER.info("Received request to create the {}", client);

        LOGGER.info("client saved");



        clientDao.save(client);

    }

}
```

For the dao's i'm using jpa repository's

So the question is how can i insert the `fk_id_user` depending on the users who is logged in. Any idea's how i could this.

Comment: When you save your `Client`, you need to set its `user` property to the current user (guessing it has this property).

Comment: Yes but how do i get the current user who is logged in. Because when the user  is logged in i use Principal

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best way to do this. So i will not accept my answer till i figured it out :

But this is how i solved it :

I added a    `private User globalUser;` to the class.

Then i create a request mapping to set the user with the data i get in the front end from the principle user

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/setuser")
public void setuser(@RequestBody String email) {

    globalUser = userDao.findByEmail(email);

    LOGGER.info(globalUser.getId().toString());
    LOGGER.info(globalUser.getEmail());

}
```

Now i got the user from the database and immediately send it back to the front end.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getuser")
public Map<String,Object> getuser() {



    LOGGER.info(globalUser.getId().toString());
    LOGGER.info(globalUser.getEmail());

    Map<String,Object> model = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    model.put("id", globalUser.getId().toString());
    model.put("email", globalUser.getEmail());

    return model;
}
```

Then before submitting the client to the database i manually set the id. So i completely ignore the `@OneToMany` which i possible wrong.

I know this is a bit messy but i'm also looking for a better way to do this and will post the answer if i find a better solution.